# How to create a submit button that appends a value on a URL and goes to that URL after submitting?

Tags: javascript, html

So basically the requirement is that a user enters a value on a text-field and after they click submit, he is redirected to a page having the URL based on his entered value e.g:

- User enters: test
- After clicking submit it becomes a URL: http://test.example.com
- And then is redirected to that URL

I have been trying using the following code:

```
<script>
    function resetId(){
  var idInput = document.getElementById("id");
  var suffix=".example.com";            
alert("Value before submit:" + idInput.value);
}
</script>

<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="resetId();return false" >
    <input type="text" name="id" value="domain" id="id"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I was able to append the it as a suffix but then Im also confused as because this is  URL I would need the whole thing, so I assume there is a better way to fulfill this instead of doing what I already am.

Apologies as I'm new to coding and I'm still learning new concepts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve it.

One-liner approach utilizing [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) (which creates a pop-up window prompting the user to enter something).

```js
window.location.replace(`http://${prompt('Input:')}.example.com`)
```

Using form and its `onsubmit` attribute (your approach). Note that for ES6, please use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of `var`.

```js
function resetId(){
    const idInput = document.getElementById("id");
    const url = `http://${idInput.value}.example.com`;
    alert("Value before submit: " + url);
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="resetId();" >
    <input type="text" name="id" value="domain" id="id">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

An approach without using a form but a button instead.

```js
// Same as above
function resetId(){
    const idInput = document.getElementById("id");
    const url = `http://${idInput.value}.example.com`;
    alert("Value before submit: " + url);
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="id">Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="domain" id="id">
</div>
<button onclick="resetId()">submit</button>
```

Note: Instead of using `<br />` for new lines in the form, consider using `<label>` and `<input>` wrapped in a `<div>` like the following for each line:

```
<div>
    <label for="something">Something:</label>
    <input type="text" name="something" id="something" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot!, this was exactly what I was looking for. The fact that you also provided tips and other ways to resolve this was also very helpful for my understanding.

Answer (score -1):

just replace this line of code

```
<form action="#" method="GET" onsubmit="resetId();return false" >
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. It looks like you are proposing to change the form's method from POST to GET, but that doesn't make any sense and the `onsubmit` function prevents the form from ever being submitted.